# C# The 'new' keyword on existing objects

Tags: c#, object, garbage-collection, new-operator

I was wondering as to what happens to an object (in C#), once its reference becomes reassigned. Example:

```
Car c = new Car("Red Car");
c = new Car("Blue Car");
```

Since the reference was reused, does the garbage collector dispose / handle the 'Red Car' after it's lost its reference? Or does a separate method need to be implemented to dispose of the 'red car'?

I'm primarily wondering because there's a relatively large object that I'm going to recycle, and need to know if there is anything that should be done when it gets recreated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In your example, the `Red Car` instance of `c` will become eligible for garbage collection when `c` is assigned to `Blue Car`. You don't need to do anything.

Check out this (old, but still relevant) MSDN article about the .NET garbage collector. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20090217212443/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx)

The first paragraph says it all:

> Garbage collection in the Microsoft .NET common language runtime environment completely absolves the developer from tracking memory usage and knowing when to free memory.

Comment: It might be worth calling `Dispose`, depending on the type in question.

Comment: Assuming there are no other references to the original object (including unregistered event handlers), you are correct.

Comment: @Phil: True but not helpful. Dispose should be called if it's there, but that's an exception and only needed when resources other than memory need to be cleaned up.

Comment: The class loads plugins via Assemble.Load(), and stores the classes / plugins into an array. I figured that would be considered part of the object. I'm not sure if this changes anything

Comment: @Richard:  I'd stay away from saying it gets "disposed" as that implies that the `IDisposable.Dispose` method will be called if defined, but that's not the case.  So that's misleading.  Also, I think your quote of the first paragraph is also a bit misleading.  `IDiposable` is an important part of the GC process as well, so while that paragraph is true for pure managed types, _completely absolves_ is very misleading for those that will stumble across your answer.

Comment: @Dan, @Andy: I've rephrased my answer. If you're happy with it could you update or remove your comment, or feel free to improve my answer if you prefer.

Answer (score 34):

> *Since the reference was reused*, does the garbage collector dispose / handle the 'Red Car' after it's lost it's reference?

You're looking at this in perhaps the wrong way:

```
c [*] ----> [Car { Name = "Red Car" }]  // Car c = new Car("Red Car")
```

Then your next step:

```
c [*]       [Car { Name = "Red Car"  }] // No chain of references to this object
   \------> [Car { Name = "Blue Car" }] // c = new Car("Blue Car")
```

The GC will come along and "collect" any of these objects which have [no chain of references to a live object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088.aspx) at some point in the future. For most tasks, as long as you're using *managed* data, you should not worry about large objects versus small objects.

For most tasks you only worry about *deterministic* memory management when dealing with [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2.aspx). As long as you follow the best practice of `using`-blocks, you will generally be fine.

Comment: Note that whether an object has *references* is not what the GC is checking. The GC is checking whether there is a *path of references from something known to be alive* to the object. An object may have a reference from something, but if that something is itself dead then that reference doesn't count.

Comment: Thanks, I struggled with how much to include (I went back and added a bit about `IDisposable`). I'll update to clarify.

Answer (score 7):

You create a new object and assign a reference to it to your variable `c`. At the same time the previous object (the "red car") is now not referenced anymore and may be garbage collected.

Answer (score 6):

If there are no other references to Red car, it will be collected by the GC on its next cycle. You don't need anything extra (unless it's a class that has streams etc. that need to be disposed)

Answer (score 5):

The garbage collector will handle cleanup for the red car when it is not longer rooted (not reachable). You, the developer, don't generally have to worry about cleaning up memory in .Net.

There are three caveats that need to be mentioned:

1. It won't happen right away.  Garbage collection will happen when it happens. You can't predict it.
2. If the type implements IDisposable, it's up to you to make sure the .Dispose() method is called.  A `using` statement is a good way to accomplish this.
3. You mentioned it's a large object. If it's more than 85000 bytes it will stored in a place called the Large Object Heap, which has very different rules for garbage collection.  Allowing this kind of object to be recycled frequently can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector will take care of disposing of Car object

Answer (score 0):

The GC will pick up your `Red Car` object and dispose of it.

You can call a custom destructor or implement IDisposable if you have resources that need to be released when the original object is no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

In case `Car` holds some native resources you'll want to implement `IDisposable` and dispose of it properly before reusing the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement the IDispose interface to clean up unmanaged resources

```
public class car : IDispose
```